# Prevent Zend Server CE from loading at start up Mac OS X?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, zend-studio

I installed the latest version of Zend Server CE on my MacBook Pro and I would like for someone to instruct me how to stop it from loading upon start up.  I only want it operational if I choose to start it.  I'm sure it's simple but so far, I can't find this information anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I installed it too and it doesn't start while booting... I need to start it manually...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://bit.ly/WemVm5

Essentially, you need to either remove entirely or (as I did) simply comment out all of the code inside `ZendServer_init`; once that is done, reboot your Mac and Zend Server CE should not automatically load anymore.